# c# Modulus Why is there errors?

Tags: c#

```
 var myMoney: int = 128;
 var cookiePrice: int = 33;
 // Calculate the change if the maximum number of cookies are bought.
 var change: int = myMoney % cookiePrice;
 Console.ReadKey();
```

I'm trying to find the modulus but I don't understand why it cant compile.

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors in your snippet. Maybe you should read a C# book or look at some tutorials to teach yourself the language.

Comment: This is not C# syntax ...

Comment: Try to read carefully errors you are receiving - it can give you idea how to modify your code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
var myMoney = 128;
var cookiePrice = 33;
// Calculate the change if the maximum number of cookies are bought.
var change = myMoney % cookiePrice;
Console.ReadKey();
```

Not:

```
var myMoney: int = 128;
var cookiePrice: int = 33;
// Calculate the change if the maximum number of cookies are bought.
var change: int = myMoney % cookiePrice;
Console.ReadKey();
```

As suggested in the comments. You should familiarize yourself first on the basics of C#. You can check the [Microsoft .NET Getting Started with C#](https://www.microsoft.com/net/tutorials/csharp/getting-started).

Comment: Glad to help! You can now accept it as an answer as reference for others.

Comment: Note that `var` is an implicit type declaration, so you don't need to specify what type your variable is, since the compiler will already know. You **can** do it explicitly, e.g. `int myMoney = 128;` but there's really no point, it only adds that bit of extra readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the exceptions you get.
You have some syntax errors in your code

The type of a variable belongs in front of the name. And you can't use : like you did it as variable name.

This would work.

```
var myMoney = 128;
var cookiePrice = 33;
// Calculate the change if the maximum number of cookies are bought.
var change = myMoney % cookiePrice;
Console.ReadKey();
```

I recommend to read a book or some online tutorials to get started with C#. One important step is to understand what you are doing wrong when you can't compile or get runtime errors. Because you can help yourself in an easy and fast way with a lot of problems. Good luck! ;)

Comment: Thank You, will do! Currently reading up on the basic. Thanks for the advice!! I will take note of that! :)